# Newman pass variable from GitLab

Tags: variables, gitlab, postman, gitlab-ci, newman

I have pipeline on GitLab and there the variable - ENV_VAR. This variable is changing based on branch for pipeline.

In the same yml file I have script with newman, where I want to pass this variable like this -> newman run ... -e test/apis/**$ENV_VAR**_environment.json

But the issue I have right now is that it seems the variable is not being passed as i want. The pipeline shows error - cannot read the test/apis/*here_should_be_the_variable_name.json*

Is there a way to pass this variable into the file source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only need to enclose the variable name in braces:

```
-e test/apis/${ENV_VAR}_environment.json
```

because `test/apis/$ENV_VAR_environment.json` means that it looks for `$ENV_VAR_environment` variable which obviously does not exist.